# How to get table name from database id, file id, page id in MS SQL 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-deadlocks, dbcc

I've deadlock graph in which the locked resource is mentioned by these three fields DB ID, File ID, Page ID. There is also some associated objectid.
All I want to know is what table this page belongs.
I tried `DBCC PAGE(dbid, fileid, pageid) with tableresults` but that doesn't show any table name.

Any idea how to get this?

Update: Also tried `SELECT name From sys.indexes WHERE object_id = 123 and Index_id = 456`
Here 123 is `m_objid` (next `ObjectId`) and 456 is `m_indexid` (next `IndexId`) which I get as output for `DBCC Page` command. All I get is NULL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get results from `DBCC PAGE` you must enable traceflag 3604, otherwise the results go to the SQL server log:

```
dbcc traceon (3604)
```

then try the command

```
dbcc page ( dbid, filenum, pagenum , 3)
```

The fourth parameter is `printopt`:

> The printopt parameter has the
>   following meanings:
>
> ```
> 0 - print just the page header
> 1 - page header plus per-row hex dumps and a dump of the page slot array 
>     (unless it's a page that doesn't > have one, like allocation bitmaps)
> 2 - page header plus whole page hex dump
> 3 - page header plus detailed per-row interpretation
> ```

definition from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/10/625659.aspx)